# PHP - cannot Host - SQL flow error

Tags: php, sql, hosting

I want to upload my program from `c9.io` to `Versio.nl`.

I downloaded `FileZilla`
Uploaded everything
Created database on the server
But I keep on receiving errors with `mysqli_driver` and credentials.

This is the first time I try to upload a project to a server

Comment: *Edit question* : Please paste your error here.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'10.3.0.57' (using password: YES)

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 135

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/e/domains/ekatelv57.fiftyseven.axc.nl/public_html/workspace/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 569

Comment: Grant Access To That User @Kate .

Answer (score 0):

You need to update all the places where you define the connection to the db.

Set the user, the password and the host as specified by the hosting provider and the error 1 will be fixed

The second error is coming because of the first and should probably disappear after fixing the first

Comment: I keep on receiving 
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'ekatelv57-ra'@'10.3.0.57' (using password: YES)

Comment: Shall I put the access hosts listed.. I have three?

Comment: This means you are using the wrong access credentials. They may be different from the ftp ones